# Multiple select statement on single table

Tags: mysql, statements

What I want to achieve is give a user the ability to query the database for particular transactions of value say "34666" & name within a given period. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Ledger WHERE transactiondate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-10-10') WHERE name='Customer' OR surnname='Customer' OR fullnames LIKE %Customer% AND (credit="34666" OR debit="34666") sub ORDER BY transactionid ASC;
```

But the above obviously is not right statement. Just to give an idea of what I want to achieve. Getting an "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias" error message with above. Tried using alias but am not really good with complex MySql queries and got it all muddled up.

**Table has columns:**

```
transactionid 
transactiondate 
name 
surname 
fullnames 
credit 
debit 
amount 
reference
```

Want to loop through and output every row matching the query.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mayur for the edits that made my question better outlined. You guys have been of more help than I thought possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a subquery here at all, I don't know why you thought to use one:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ledger
WHERE
    transactiondate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-10-10' AND
    (name = 'Customer' OR surnname = 'Customer' OR fullnames LIKE '%Customer%') AND
    (credit = '34666' OR debit = '34666')
ORDER BY
    transactionid;
```

The exact cause of your error is that your query has a subquery without an alias.  There *does* appear to be an alias `sub` in there, but it is out place.  It should have appeared right after the end of the subquery.  But again, I don't think you need a subquery here.

Comment: You Legend! Respects unlimited. Thanks Tim. Obviously could have saved myself much headache if I asked for help hours ago. Thanks.